# Back In Time lost my backup profiles (ie configuration) -- in GUI only

Tags: backup, rsync, backintime

This seems a bit odd to me. In very short, as noted in the question BackInTime seems to have lost my backup profiles -- or perhaps more accurately, is not able to pull information about the profiles from its `config` file as detailed below.

To jump to the question: **Is there a way to somehow force BiT to read the `config` file and re-create(?) the profile(s) in the GUI?**

Anyways, to the description / full account:

**Here's what I did:**

1. Created the `Main profile` in the BackInTime GUI with all info added (Included, Excluded folders / file types, etc configurations).
   [image]
2. Took three successful snapshots with the profile. 
   [image]
3. Created a second backup profile.
4. Rebooted my computer in anticipation of taking a snapshot with the second profile as the system had accumulated 15 GB cache per system monitor during the three runs of the `Main profile` and it seemed a bit sluggish. (I should perhaps add that this installation doesn't shut down fully properly so I need to force close the computer by long-pressing the power button. Systems booted up ok nevertheless as usual.)
5. Started up BackInTime again -- but had forgotten to mount my external USB3-connected backup location (which is ext4).
6. BiT gave a prompt noting that my destination is on a removable media and not attached. Asked to attach/mount it and click ok. Which I did. 
   *Now, finally:*
7. BiT shows essentially a blank screen. As if I would have just started it for the first time.

**Some additional notes:**

- My BiT's config file at `~/.config/backintime/config` seems just fine. (I've copy-pasted it at the bottom of this question.)
- After exiting and restarting BiT 2-3 times and then rebooting my computer, opening up BiT again and *then* noticing the `Refresh snapshot list` (as shown below) I was able to get BiT list the snapshots I have taken 
  [image]
  ... but
- BiT is still not seeing any of my configurations
- Consequently, BiT is not showing anything in the Shortcuts or Name windows. 
  [image]

I'm a bit clueless in how I could troubleshoot this further. I've tried to search the web for things like "Ubuntu Back In Time lost backup profile" etc but haven't really found anything that would get me ahead. I've rebooted the computer again but the profile details (that still exist in the `config` file just doesn't get pulled into BiT.

All/any advice would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 amd64 in a dual-boot setup (w/ the other boot being Win7, not that it would matter AFAIK). This is a few days old installation and I installed BiT from Ubuntu Software Center. Its version is 1.0.36. Rsync version is 3.1.1  protocol version 31. As noted in my text my Ubuntu installation isn't totally perfect as it's not shutting down properly but needs to be force-closed with long-pressing the power button. I don't understand Linux well enough that I would understand if that causes problems -- e.g. for saving created profiles' information as *might* be the issue here. All of the at least 20 software that I've installed and tried seem to run pretty ok, though. I haven't had any problems with other configurations not being saved, to be specific (in relation to this problem).

---

### **My BackInTime `~/.config/backintime/config` file contents**

```
gnome.last_path=None
gnome.main_window.height=718
gnome.main_window.hpaned1=200
gnome.main_window.hpaned2=200
gnome.main_window.width=2661
gnome.main_window.x=171
gnome.main_window.y=819
gnome.show_hidden_files=false
profile1.snapshots.automatic_backup_anacron_period=1
profile1.snapshots.automatic_backup_day=1
profile1.snapshots.automatic_backup_mode=20
profile1.snapshots.automatic_backup_time=1600
profile1.snapshots.automatic_backup_weekday=1
profile1.snapshots.backup_on_restore.enabled=true
profile1.snapshots.bwlimit.enabled=false
profile1.snapshots.bwlimit.value=3000
profile1.snapshots.check_for_changes=true
profile1.snapshots.continue_on_errors=true
profile1.snapshots.copy_links=false
profile1.snapshots.copy_unsafe_links=false
profile1.snapshots.cron.ionice=true
profile1.snapshots.cron.nice=true
profile1.snapshots.custom_backup_time=8,12,18,23
profile1.snapshots.dont_remove_named_snapshots=true
profile1.snapshots.exclude.1.value=.gvfs
profile1.snapshots.exclude.10.value=/sys/*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.11.value=/dev/*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.12.value=/run/*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.13.value=/media/MyUserName/MyData/System Volume Information
profile1.snapshots.exclude.14.value=/media/MyUserName/MyData/$RECYCLE.BIN
profile1.snapshots.exclude.2.value=.cache*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.3.value=[Cc]ache*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.4.value=.thumbnails*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.5.value=[Tt]rash*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.6.value=*.backup*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.7.value=*~
profile1.snapshots.exclude.8.value=.dropbox*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.9.value=/proc/*
profile1.snapshots.exclude.size=14
profile1.snapshots.full_rsync=true
profile1.snapshots.include.1.type=0
profile1.snapshots.include.1.value=/media/MyUserName/MyData
profile1.snapshots.include.size=1
profile1.snapshots.local.password.save=false
profile1.snapshots.local.password.use_cache=true
profile1.snapshots.local_encfs.path=/media/MyUserName/4TB-1/Backups/Laptop-MyUserName
profile1.snapshots.log_level=3
profile1.snapshots.min_free_inodes.enabled=true
profile1.snapshots.min_free_inodes.value=2
profile1.snapshots.min_free_space.enabled=true
profile1.snapshots.min_free_space.unit=20
profile1.snapshots.min_free_space.value=1
profile1.snapshots.mode=local
profile1.snapshots.no_on_battery=false
profile1.snapshots.notify.enabled=true
profile1.snapshots.path=/media/MyUserName/4TB-1/Backups/Laptop-MyUserName
profile1.snapshots.path.auto=true
profile1.snapshots.path.host=MyComputerName
profile1.snapshots.path.profile=1
profile1.snapshots.path.user=MyUserName
profile1.snapshots.preserve_acl=false
profile1.snapshots.preserve_xattr=false
profile1.snapshots.remove_old_snapshots.enabled=true
profile1.snapshots.remove_old_snapshots.unit=80
profile1.snapshots.remove_old_snapshots.value=10
profile1.snapshots.smart_remove=false
profile1.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_all=2
profile1.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_one_per_day=7
profile1.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_one_per_month=24
profile1.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_one_per_week=4
profile1.snapshots.ssh.cipher=default
profile1.snapshots.ssh.host=
profile1.snapshots.ssh.ionice=false
profile1.snapshots.ssh.nice=false
profile1.snapshots.ssh.path=
profile1.snapshots.ssh.port=22
profile1.snapshots.ssh.private_key_file=/home/MyUserName/.ssh/id_rsa
profile1.snapshots.ssh.user=MyUserName
profile1.snapshots.use_checksum=false
profile1.snapshots.user_backup.ionice=false
profile2.snapshots.automatic_backup_anacron_period=1
profile2.snapshots.automatic_backup_day=1
profile2.snapshots.automatic_backup_mode=30
profile2.snapshots.automatic_backup_time=2000
profile2.snapshots.automatic_backup_weekday=7
profile2.snapshots.backup_on_restore.enabled=true
profile2.snapshots.bwlimit.enabled=false
profile2.snapshots.bwlimit.value=3000
profile2.snapshots.check_for_changes=true
profile2.snapshots.continue_on_errors=true
profile2.snapshots.copy_links=false
profile2.snapshots.copy_unsafe_links=false
profile2.snapshots.cron.ionice=true
profile2.snapshots.cron.nice=true
profile2.snapshots.custom_backup_time=8,12,18,23
profile2.snapshots.dont_remove_named_snapshots=true
profile2.snapshots.exclude.1.value=.gvfs
profile2.snapshots.exclude.10.value=/sys/*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.11.value=/dev/*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.12.value=/run/*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.13.value=/media/MyUserName/Data/System Volume Information
profile2.snapshots.exclude.14.value=/media/MyUserName/Data/$RECYCLE.BIN
profile2.snapshots.exclude.15.value=/media/MyUserName/Data/(dot)marble-data-maps-earth
profile2.snapshots.exclude.17.value=/media/MyUserName/Data/Music (mobile)
profile2.snapshots.exclude.18.value=/media/MyUserName/Data/Temp
profile2.snapshots.exclude.2.value=.cache*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.3.value=[Cc]ache*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.4.value=.thumbnails*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.5.value=[Tt]rash*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.6.value=*.backup*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.7.value=*~
profile2.snapshots.exclude.8.value=.dropbox*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.9.value=/proc/*
profile2.snapshots.exclude.size=18
profile2.snapshots.full_rsync=true
profile2.snapshots.include.1.type=0
profile2.snapshots.include.1.value=/media/MyUserName/Data
profile2.snapshots.include.size=1
profile2.snapshots.local.password.save=false
profile2.snapshots.local.password.use_cache=true
profile2.snapshots.local_encfs.path=/media/MyUserName/4TB-1/Backups/Laptop-MyUserName
profile2.snapshots.log_level=3
profile2.snapshots.min_free_inodes.enabled=true
profile2.snapshots.min_free_inodes.value=2
profile2.snapshots.min_free_space.enabled=true
profile2.snapshots.min_free_space.unit=20
profile2.snapshots.min_free_space.value=1
profile2.snapshots.mode=local
profile2.snapshots.no_on_battery=false
profile2.snapshots.notify.enabled=true
profile2.snapshots.path=/media/MyUserName/4TB-1/Backups/Laptop-MyUserName
profile2.snapshots.path.auto=true
profile2.snapshots.path.host=MyComputerName
profile2.snapshots.path.profile=2
profile2.snapshots.path.user=MyUserName
profile2.snapshots.preserve_acl=false
profile2.snapshots.preserve_xattr=false
profile2.snapshots.remove_old_snapshots.enabled=true
profile2.snapshots.remove_old_snapshots.unit=80
profile2.snapshots.remove_old_snapshots.value=10
profile2.snapshots.smart_remove=false
profile2.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_all=2
profile2.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_one_per_day=7
profile2.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_one_per_month=24
profile2.snapshots.smart_remove.keep_one_per_week=4
profile2.snapshots.ssh.cipher=default
profile2.snapshots.ssh.host=
profile2.snapshots.ssh.ionice=false
profile2.snapshots.ssh.nice=false
profile2.snapshots.ssh.path=
profile2.snapshots.ssh.port=22
profile2.snapshots.ssh.private_key_file=/home/MyUserName/.ssh/id_rsa
profile2.snapshots.ssh.user=MyUserName
profile2.snapshots.use_checksum=false
profile2.snapshots.user_backup.ionice=false
profiles=1:2
profiles.version=1
```

Comment: What version are you using?  Here it just works after I quit BackInTime, attach the drive and then start it again...

Comment: @Fabby problem here is the missing `profile2.name` in config. No matter which version you use. I checked it with 1.0.36 and 1.1.4

Answer (score 2):

Your second profile is missing a name. I'm not sure how this could happen because I double checked in BIT source and it should refuse to create a new profiles without name. Anyways, please run `echo "profile2.name=Second Profile" | tee -a ~/.config/backintime/config` to fix this.

#### Edit

BackInTime version 1.1.6 (planned to release next week) will avoid this by using a default profile name if the value is missing.

---

Regarding 4.
You should never switch of your machine by holding power button. This can lead to disc corruption as files doesn't get written directly to your hdd. They are cached in RAM. Only a clean dismount would make sure that all files have been written to hdd.

To avoid this but switch off your machine after it crashed you can press and hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PRINT</kbd> and type (while holding) <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT-Dev Team</sub>

Comment: Ah!  Good one! (shouldn't we create a BackInTimetag if members of the BiT Team lurk in the shadows???)  **;-)**

Comment: I did already and I'm also subscribed to it. That's how I got attention on this ;-)